# Argument is missing even though 2 variables given

Tags: python, python-3.7

I need to store num_of_divisions and num_of_classes in the object School

file1.py

```
import file1

name_of_school=input("Enter name of Schoool\n")
printschool=f"Your School's name is {name_of_school}"
print(printschool)

try:
   num_of_class=int(input("How many class are there in your School?\n"))
except (ValueError, TypeError) as okok:
   print("Please Enter a valid number")
else:
    if num_of_class<=0:
        print("Number cannot be zero or less")
    else:
        printvalue=f"Number of class in school are {num_of_class}"
        print(printvalue)

num_of_divisions=[]
for divisionloop in range(num_of_class):
    divisionloop=divisionloop+1
    num_of_divisions.append(int(input("Enter number of Divisions for class %d:"%(divisionloop))))

pak=file1.School.mouse(num_of_class, num_of_divisions)
print(pak)
```

fil2.py
this file below is a module

```
class School:
    def mouse(self, num_of_class, num_of_divisions):
        print(num_of_class and num_of_divisions)
        self.num_of_class=num_of_class
        self.num_of_divisions=num_of_divisions
        return num_of_class
```

```
Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ttmain.py", line 24, in <module>
    pak=classes.School.mouse(num_of_class, num_of_divisions)
TypeError: mouse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num_of_divisions'
```

plus I need mouse to return value of num_of_class and num_of_divisions both

Comment: you should first create instance of class `variable = file1.School()` and later use its method `variable.takla(num_of_class, num_of_divisions)` and then Python will run it as `School.takla(variable, num_of_class, num_of_divisions)` - so it will assign `variable` to `self` and other values to variables `num_of_class, num_of_divisions` in `def takla(...)`

Comment: BTW: your error message shows problem with `classes.School.takla` but you don't show it in your code.

Comment: @furas thanks, i changed method name for question and forgot to change it in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create instance of your `School` class first and then you can access the mouse function.

```
schoolObj = file1.School()
return_value = schoolObj.mouse(num_of_class, num_of_divisions)
print(return_value)
```